# can a sibling go to a burial in a non jewish cemetery

Tags: gentiles, cemetery-grave

A Jewish man married to a non-Jewish woman dies. He is buried in either a non-Jewish cemetery or in a section designated for Jews. Can siblings go to the cemetery for the burial or a visit?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: There is some lack of clarity in your question. Did you mean "he is buried in a non-Jewish cemetery, either in a section designated for Jews or one for non-Jews"? If not what are the two options you are asking about?

Answer (score 7):

There is no problem to go to non-Jewish cemeteries, and it is even [encouraged on fast days](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.579.3?lang=bi) (as a reminder of our mortality) if there is no nearby Jewish cemetery.
Per [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/108440), prayers should not be said if there are prominent non-Jewish religious symbols around the grave.