Is it permitted to visit Palermo catacombs in Sicily?
Is a Jew halachically permitted to visit the catacombs in Palermo Sicily?
Are these catacombs beneath the church?

Are they a part of the church?

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108437/can-you-pray-or-study-torah-in-a-non-jewish-cemetery/108440

Welcome to MiYodeya Bella and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Your question seems to be dependent on the specific details of the site you want to visit, which we cannot know about, unless you get lucky and one of the site respondents happens to have been there
